# What do I do if I find a user marking almost every post in Triage as "Looks OK"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, users

I was reviewing in Triage when I flagged a question as `Unsalvageable` and decided to go back to the review to see what others marked the question as and saw that one user marked it as `Looks OK`.  I moved on and saw another bad question that I marked as `Unsalvageable`, looked at other reviews for the question, and saw that the same user marked it as `Looks OK`.  I looked at the user's review history and saw that they just started reviewing after not reviewing since January 24 (67 days ago), and every single review they had made in the last 3 hours was either  `Looks OK` or `No Action Needed`, including several clearly not OK posts.  Should I flag one of their posts so a mod can look at it?  Should I link the profile in this post?

Comment: Yes, raise a moderator flag when you see something bad happening in /review, or anywhere else. Yes, give us whatever information you think we will need in order to locate and reproduce the problem. You're a programmer; you know this. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray just wondering if it would be considered a bad flag, thanks

Comment: The purpose of a flag is to be private, thus avoiding the Meta effect. No need to link the profile here.